# Google Play Services: Show Account Picker Only Once?

Tags: android, google-play-services, account, picker

I want to show the Google Play account picker only once (the first time the game boot up). If the user connects to Google Play, it should auto connect (and it's doing ok right now). But if the user doesn't connect, the picker shouldn't be shown. Now, if the user doesn't connect, the "connect" method displays the account picker. I don't know how to disable it.

I use this code to create the client:

```
sGameClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(sActivity)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(sCallbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(sCallbacks)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
```

And this to connect:

```
sGameClient.connect ();
```

The full source code:

https://github.com/moaiforge/moai-sdk/blob/1.6_admob_ios/src/moai-android-google-play-services/MoaiGooglePlayServices.java

Thanks!

Comment: You can save a boolean flag in your shared preferences if the user says no to google connect. Then next time check for this value from shared prefs and do tthe things accordingly.

Comment: Yes I was thinking on something like this. But also I thought that Google had done something for this situations...

Comment: Why do you need to disable `account picker`, is it show up twice? Take look at [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/aSZ-0VrZjY4) may give you some idea.

Comment: It is very tedious to see every time the account picker if you don't want to login...

Comment: I find the method/doc to `Invoke the Account Picker` [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth#invoke_the_account_picker). If you don't want to show the account picker, you don't need to invoke it I think